# Ionic Ios UINavigationBar Overlaps View

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, uinavigationbar

I'm using Ionic Framework to build a app with a header.

The ionic header is implemented correctly but it`s being overlapped by UINavigationBar when running in Ios Device or simulator.

It's strange because it works correctly when testing in browser but it gets overlapped when in Iphone.

Open the images link to see it!

Screens:  https://mega.nz/#F!TMBRXKBC!Ajd7FghDYQ5D3rf3f5rZsQ

Images explanation:

1- working example in browser

2- overlapping in xcode debugger

3- overlapping example in iphone

4- when i turn the device, i can see the nav behind